# JavaFx use String with Double on table column

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a class called "Product", with a double attribute "price". I'm showing it on a table column inside a table view, but i wanted to show the price formatted -- "US$ 20.00" instead of just "20.00".

Here's my code for populating the table view:

```
priceProductColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());
```

I tried everything: convert the returned value to a string, using the method toString that priceProperty has, etc, but not seems to work.

Do i need to bind an event of something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `cellValueFactory` as you have it to determine the data that is displayed. The cell value factory is basically a function that takes a `CellDataFeatures` object and returns an `ObservableValue` wrapping up the value to be displayed in the table cell. You usually want to call `getValue()` on the `CellDataFeatures` object to get the value for the row, and then retrieve a property from it, exactly as you do in your posted code.

Use a `cellFactory` to determine how to display those data. The `cellFactory` is a function that takes a `TableColumn` (which you usually don't need) and returns a `TableCell` object. Typically you return a subclass of `TableCell` that override the `updateItem()` method to set the text (and sometimes the graphic) for the cell, based on the new value it is displaying. In your case you get the price as a `Number`, and just need to format it as you require and pass the formatted value to the cell's `setText(...)` method.

It's worth reading the relevant Javadocs: [`TableColumn.cellFactoryProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty--), and also [`Cell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) for a general discussion of cells and cell factories.

```
priceProductColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());

priceProductColumn.setCellFactory(col -> 
    new TableCell<Product, Number>() {
        @Override 
        public void updateItem(Number price, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(price, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(String.format("US$%.2f", price.doubleValue()));
            }
        }
    });
```

(I'm assuming `priceProductColumn` is a `TableColumn<Product, Number>` and `Product.priceProperty()` returns a `DoubleProperty`.)

Comment: Thanks!! Could you explain the code a little bit? I'm still a begginer in Java.

Comment: Basically what he does is to override the original cellFactor of the column. Then, if the price is empty the text shouldn't be anything, and if the price isn't empty, the column text should be the price.The string format adds the US $ in front of the price.  Read more about String Format here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

Comment: Updated with a description.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not, read this together with @James_D post.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm