# How to prevent scientific notation in SimpleDoubleProperty

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm building a table in Java FX and using `SimpleDoubleProperty` properties, quite straightforwardly like this:

```
property.set(3000000D);
```

However when this renders on screen I get the scientific notation `3E6`. How can I prevent this and show the "proper" number?

I suppose I could use `SimpleStringProperty` instead but thought there might be a way...

**EDIT**

There is a 3rd duplicate which was more useful: [TableView column data set to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917983/tableview-column-data-set-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318989/showing-doubleproperty-up-to-two-decimal-places-in-tableview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117949/javafx-use-string-with-double-on-table-column

Comment: When it "renders" on screen how?  Did you output it by requesting console output, or are you using some manner of inspector, or yet a third technique?

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner by "renders" i mean in the table cell on the GUI.

Comment: @assylias you're right, I see those questions both answer what I'm after - thanks - voting to close this.